# What is the time complexity of random.choice in python and how does it actually work?

Tags: python, random, time

I've been looking through documentation and I still don't understand how it is randomly selecting an element and what time complexity it is doing it with. Hoping to get a more in depth understanding of how this works under the hood. Appreciate any insight!

Comment: I think this is an instance where either looking beyond the docs for already published articles or blogposts would be the only alternative reading the actual source code.

Comment: From the docs- `Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator`. From the source-`.choice` uses a randomly generated integer that is used to index the sequence. Indexing a sequence should be O(1) - guess you'll have to study the  *Mersenne Twister* to find it's Time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html (3.10),

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator.
> The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random
> number generators in existence. However, being completely
> deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely
> unsuitable for cryptographic purposes.

May you can walk through below link (as pointed by @wwii in comments) quickly to understand the implementation details (look for `random.choice`, `random.choices`).

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31a390e43f2ea2608c5ec04de7d012df14f16fda/Lib/random.py#L375

```
def choice(self, seq):
```

and

```
 def choices(self, population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1):
```

For the first method the time complexity is **O(1)**

For the other method
when `k == n`, there is one `for` loop, so it could be **O(n)**

Comment: That looks a bit different than the [repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31a390e43f2ea2608c5ec04de7d012df14f16fda/Lib/random.py#L375) linked to by the Python docs.

Comment: @wwii yours is more accurate. Thanks I will update the link